# Area of a closed figure under dilation confusion

Tags: geometry, area

In *A First Course in Calculus*, on the topic of 'Sine and Cosine', it is written that,

> Let $S$ be any region in the plane. Let $A$ be the area of $S$. Under dilation by a factor $r$, the dilated region has area $r^2A$.

Followed by the image of,

[image: A region S with area A, and a region rS with area r^2A]

Essentially, the book drew a band of width $2c\sqrt2$ along the length of the boundary, then stated that the area of the band (given by $2cl\sqrt2$, where $l$ was the length of the boundary), approaches $0$ as $c$ approaches $0$. So the area of the region is given by the approximate sum of the areas of the squares enclosed within the figure.
This I have no problem with. But when dilating under a factor of $r$, the equation for the area of the band given was $2r^2cl\sqrt2$. My conclusion for the area of the band however, was $2rcl\sqrt2$ which I derived by drawing a square of side $rc$, finding the length of the diagonal, multiplying this by 2, then multiplying this entire width by the length of the boundary. But this differs from what is written.

And this is essentially where I am confused. Where has my line of thinking gone wrong? Perhaps (and most likely), I've misinterpreted the meaning of the following line, but can't seem to understand what are we dilating here; the grid, the figure or both?

> Under dilation, a similar argument applies to the dilated band of the dilated figure, so that the area of the dilated band is at most $2r^2c\sqrt2$ times the length of the boundary.

For further clarity, I understand the idea of the area of a region becoming $r^2A$ after dilation by a factor of $r$. But just torn between my own derivation and following the above concept.

Comment: Did you consider the fact that the length of the boundary becomes $rl$?

Comment: I did not... Now it makes sense! Thank you.